# The number of functions $ f : \left \{ 1, 2, . . . , 10 \right \} \rightarrow \left \{ 1, 2, . . . , 10 \right \}$ such that $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

### Question

> The number of functions $ f : \left \{ 1, 2, . . . , 10 \right \} \rightarrow \left \{ 1, 2, . . . , 10 \right \}$ such that $f(x) \neq   x$ for all $x$ is

### Approach

Total number of function possible $=10^{10}$

But with the restriction ,$f(x) \neq   x$ for all $x$,

Eg-:$f(1)\neq 1 $ each element in the domain will have 1 less available option in the range .

So total number of function possible$=9^{10}$

Am I correct?

please help.

Comment: "Am I correct?"  Yes.  (That was easy.)

Comment: i am confused that why dearrangement will not work here ?

Comment: Derangements imply that the functions are bijective. In your case, functions are not required to be bijective.

Comment: Derangements would be precisely the way to solve this if the function had to be bijective-- that is if $f(1)\ne 1$ and $f(2)\ne 2;f(3)\ne f(1)$ and $f(3)\ne 3; f(3)\ne f(2); f(3) \ne f(1)$ etc.  But in this promblem $f(2)$ can equal $f(1)$ if you want to.  *Everything* (except $f(f(1))$) can equal $f(1)$ if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every input, you have 9 choices for output. As $f(x)=x$ is not allowed. So, total no. of ways is $9^{10}$

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: If functions are not bijective.

It's a simple case for every $i^{th}$ element ,$1\le i\le 10$, you have 9 possibilities to choose from for the output.

Hence total number of functions=$ 9^{10}$

Case 2: If functions are bijective

On close observation you might notice that what you need is exactly the number of [Derangements](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) that could be done with $10$ elements. That means you need to find $$!10=\left\lfloor \frac {9!}{e}+\frac 12\right\rfloor =362 880    $$

Comment: The functions are not necessarily bijective.

Comment: @Antoine Guard Thanks. Edited accordingly